# Misunderstanding the List monad

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm confused about why I'm getting the following output for my program:

```
-- test.hs

f :: Int -> [[Int]]
f 0 = []
f x = do
  y <- [0, 1]
  g <- f (x - 1)
  return (y : g)

main :: IO ()
main = print $ f 2
```

I expect the output of this program to be

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
```

However, all I get is

```
$ ghc -o test test.hs && ./test
[]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

`f 0 = [[]]`

Looks like f x generates of bitwise combinations of length x, so f 0 must contain the sequence of length 0, which is the empty list.

Comment: @Mokosha You can even write that as `return []` to make it more similar to the other case.